# How to generate deterministic keys for Ethereum using Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, ethereum, bitcoinj

I'm trying to create a deterministic wallet for Ethereum mixing `BitcoinJ` and `Web3j`. The deterministic key is generated using `BitcoinJ` and the Ethereum credentials using `Web3j`. But the address generated with the `Web3j` credential is not as expected.

```
String seedCode = "yard impulse luxury drive today throw farm pepper survey wreck glass federal";

// BitcoinJ
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(seedCode, null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
DeterministicKey key = chain.getKey(KeyPurpose.RECEIVE_FUNDS);
BigInteger privKey = key.getPrivKey();

// Web3j
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privKey.toString(16));
System.out.println("Address: " + credentials.getAddress());
```

**Output**: `0x2c4186d0422d0462a48c92cd559cbc30f528855b`

**Expected**: `0x72445fcFdEB1Fff79496D7Ce66089d663Ff90E26`

Where is the misunderstanding in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `bitcoinj` uses the path **`m/0'/0`** for the chain of keys. And most of the Ethereum solutions uses **`m/44'/60'/0'/0`** from the **BIP44** specification. That's why the result wasn't as expected when comparing to other Ethereum tools.

The code below fix "the problem":

```
String seedCode = "yard impulse luxury drive today throw farm pepper survey wreck glass federal";

// BitcoinJ
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(seedCode, null, "", 1409478661L);
DeterministicKeyChain chain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(seed).build();
List<ChildNumber> keyPath = HDUtils.parsePath("M/44H/60H/0H/0/0");
DeterministicKey key = chain.getKeyByPath(keyPath, true);
BigInteger privKey = key.getPrivKey();

// Web3j
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privKey.toString(16));
System.out.println(credentials.getAddress());
```

Comment: Italo, could you please clarify whether it's possible to get an Ethereum address for DeterministicKey instance generated from extended public key only? (as it's recommended for external addresses of HD Wallets) - following to your code sample I getting "Private key bytes not available" error, that looks logical...